# Expected lifespan of ereg, migrating to preg

Tags: php, regex, ereg

I work on a large PHP application (>1 million lines, 10 yrs old) which makes extensive use of `ereg` and `ereg_replace` - currently 1,768 unique regular expressions in 516 classes.

I'm very aware why `ereg` is being deprecated but clearly migrating to `preg` could be highly involved.

Does anyone know how long `ereg` support is likely to be maintained in PHP, and/or have any advice for migrating to `preg` on this scale. I suspect automated translation from ereg to preg is impossible/impractical?

Comment: `ereg` has been discouraged since around PHP 4.1 - but solely because it is not as optimized as the PCRE functions. It's not overly likely to be removed anytime soon (not with the mythical PHP6 anyway), and even then it would be simple to write a runtime compatibility support wrapper (which you should do for testing). You should list some examples why you think your posix extended regexpressions would be incompatible. The differences are seldomly significant.

Comment: There are tools out there that can translate from `ereg` to `preg`; [RegexBuddy](http://www.regexbuddy.com) for example does this and supports COM automation. Depending on the complexity of your regexes, and whether you actually need to migrate, that might be a relevant option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure when `ereg` will be removed but my bet is as of PHP 6.0.

Regarding your second issue (translating `ereg` to `preg`) doesn't seem something that hard, if your application has > 1 million lines surely you must have the resources to get someone doing this job for a week at most. I would grep all the `ereg_` instances in your code and set up some macros in your favorite IDE (simple stuff like adding delimiters, modifiers and so on).

I bet most of the 1768 regexes can be ported using a macro, and the others, well, a good pair of eyes.

Another option might be to write wrappers around the `ereg` functions if they are not available, implementing [the changes](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.posix.php) as needed:

```
if (function_exists('ereg') !== true)
{
    function ereg($pattern, $string, &$regs)
    {
        return preg_match('~' . addcslashes($pattern, '~') . '~', $string, $regs);
    }
}

if (function_exists('eregi') !== true)
{
    function eregi($pattern, $string, &$regs)
    {
        return preg_match('~' . addcslashes($pattern, '~') . '~i', $string, $regs);
    }
}
```

You get the idea. <s>Also, [PEAR package PHP Compat](http://pear.php.net/package/PHP_Compat/) might be a viable solution too.</s>

---

> ### Differences from POSIX regex
>
> As of PHP 5.3.0, the POSIX Regex
>   extension is deprecated. There are a
>   number of differences between POSIX
>   regex and PCRE regex. This page lists
>   the most notable ones that are
>   necessary to know when converting to
>   PCRE.
>
> 1. The PCRE functions require that the pattern is enclosed by delimiters.
> 2. Unlike POSIX, the PCRE extension does not have dedicated functions for
>      case-insensitive matching. Instead,
>      this is supported using the /i pattern
>      modifier. Other pattern modifiers are
>      also available for changing the
>      matching strategy.
> 3. The POSIX functions find the longest of the leftmost match, but
>      PCRE stops on the first valid match.
>      If the string doesn't match at all it
>      makes no difference, but if it matches
>      it may have dramatic effects on both
>      the resulting match and the matching
>      speed. To illustrate this difference,
>      consider the following example from
>      "Mastering Regular Expressions" by
>      Jeffrey Friedl. Using the pattern
>      one(self)?(selfsufficient)? on the
>      string oneselfsufficient with PCRE
>      will result in matching oneself, but
>      using POSIX the result will be the
>      full string oneselfsufficient. Both
>      (sub)strings match the original
>      string, but POSIX requires that the
>      longest be the result.

Comment: More evasive would be to use `"\1"` as delimiters. Could still fail, but the other typical delimiters might already be used and needlessly prefixed with backslashes `[\-\~]+`, so addcslashes could potentially undo the escaping there (yes, too many ifs). -- The wrapper function is the only sane approach. Would add more testing/warnings, and dry-run it with runkit/override_function in OPs case.

Comment: +1 - Great answer, thanks (this was my first StackOverflow question, and I'm already impressed!)

Comment: @mario: Is `\1` a valid PCRE delimiter? Didn't knew that! =) If they are already escaped in the context of `ereg`, escaping the tildes again should have no bad consequences... Or should it be `addcslashes($pattern, '\\~')`? I'm really bad when it comes to escaping (un)escaped data, always have to test it countless times!

Comment: @Oliver: Thank you, I hope you stick around! ;)

Answer (score 2):

My intuition says that they are never going to remove `ereg` on purpose. PHP still supports really old and deprecated stuff like register globals. There're simply too many outdated apps out there. There's however a little chance that the extension has to be removed because someone finds a serious vulnerability and there's just nobody to fix it.

In any case, it's worth noting that:

1. You are not forced to upgrade your PHP installation. It's pretty common to keep outdated servers to run legady apps.
2. The [PHP_Compat](http://pear.php.net/package/PHP_Compat/) PEAR package offers plain PHP version of some native functions. If `ereg` disappears, it's possible that it gets added.

---

BTW... In fact, [PHP 6 is dead](http://www.larryullman.com/2010/05/25/the-death-of-php-6the-future-of-php-6/). They realised that their approach to make PHP fully Unicode compliant was harder than they thought and they are rethinking it all. The conclusion is: you can never make perfect predictions.

Comment: Thanks - your last link was particularly interesting. We make extensive use of multibyte/Unicode parsing and have a tonne of homegrown utility classes to support it. The promise of native support in PHP6 was enticing but terrifying to us!

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem on a much smaller scale - an application more like 10,000 lines. In every case, all I need to do was switch to `preg_replace()` and put delimiters around the regex pattern.

Anyone should be able to do that - even a non-programmer can be given a list of filenames and line numbers.

Then just run your tests to watch for any failures that can be fixed.

ereg functions will be removed from PHP6, by the way - http://jero.net/articles/php6.

Answer (score 0):

All `ereg` functions will be removed as of PHP 6, I believe.