# PHP replace ereg(i)(_replace) globally

Tags: php, replace, eregi

I have 150+ PHP files I need to change (updating ereg to preg_match). I tired to update them manually but it takes for ever and I want to make sure all my replace will work the first time. What can I do to do this kind of operation?

Here's some example of my ereg(i)

```
if(eregi("^[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}$", $ip)) { /* ... */}
if (eregi($regexp, $label, $match)) { /* ... */}
$string = eregi_replace("[[:space:]]+", ' ', $string);
```

Thanks

Comment: @JasonMcCreary YES that is why I asked this question ==> **updating ereg to preg_match**

Comment: @Jason, I think he's moving *from* ereg to preg_match.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Expected lifespan of ereg, migrating to preg](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5871312/expected-lifespan-of-ereg-migrating-to-preg)

Comment: @AlixAxel I don't want to create a function if it does not exists, I want to replace all ereg functions using a command line or something else

Comment: @BookOfZeus seem complicated? do you have an example?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash
perl -p -i -e "s/eregi_replace *\\( *\"([^\@]+?)(?<\!\\\\)\", */preg_replace(\"\@\\1\@i\", /g" $1
perl -p -i -e "s/eregi_replace *\\( *\'([^\@]+?)(?<\!\\\\)\', */preg_replace(\'\@\\1\@i\', /g" $1
perl -p -i -e "s/ereg_replace *\\( *\"([^\@]+?)(?<\!\\\\)\", */preg_replace(\"\@\\1\@\", /g" $1
perl -p -i -e "s/ereg_replace *\\( *\'([^\@]+?)(?<\!\\\\)\', */preg_replace(\'\@\\1\@\', /g" $1
perl -p -i -e "s/eregi *\\( *\"([^\@]+?)(?<\!\\\\)\", */preg_match(\"\@\\1\@i\", /g" $1
perl -p -i -e "s/eregi *\\( *\'([^\@]+?)(?<\!\\\\)\', */preg_match(\'\@\\1\@i\', /g" $1
perl -p -i -e "s/ereg *\\( *\"([^\@]+?)(?<\!\\\\)\", */preg_match(\"\@\\1\@\", /g" $1
perl -p -i -e "s/ereg *\\( *\'([^\@]+?)(?<\!\\\\)\', */preg_match(\'\@\\1\@\', /g" $1
```

Here's a little bash script that I use.  Someone with more time than me can probably squash all of this into less (1?) regular expressions, but it should do the trick.  Feel free to replace `@` with your delimiter of choice.  Just paste this into a file, `chmod +x` it, and then call it, passing the file as an argument.

If you need to use it en masse, something like this should suffice:

```
find /path/to/your/project -name '*.php' -exec foo {} \;
```

Where `foo` is whatever you named the bash script.

**Note:** This isn't perfect, so you'll still need to manually change any fringe cases that it misses, but it will still save you a lot of work.  Also note that this does in-place file edits.

Comment: What if he is trying to match an email with ereg? I would suggest to use `~` as the delimiter instead.

Comment: Variables and multiline patterns are also not covered by this.

Comment: Without knowing what he's using regexes to match in his project, no suggested delimiter is better or worse than another (especially since I noted that he should replace it with his delimiter of choice).  He may very well only be matching stuff with a lot of `~`s and no `@`s.

Comment: @Alix: Did you miss the **Note**?

Comment: Sure, I didn't payed attention to anything after your code, +1.

Comment: @drrcknlsn: I get this error: Sequence (?<\...) not recognized in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/eregi_replace *\( *"([^\@]+?)(?<\ <-- HERE !\\)", */ at -e line 1.

Comment: @Tech4Wilco: Did you modify the script at all?  It works fine for me.  Changing the quotes will mess it up.  The sequence `(?<!` is a negative lookbehind.  It's written as `(?<\!` to escape the `!`, which has special meaning in bash.  I suppose you could try not escaping it and see if that works for you.

Comment: I use the code I put in my question and execute your code. I will try

Answer (score 0):

replacing the actual ereg call would be a fairly simple matter of doing a search/replace operation. But actually fixing up your pattern to include the delimiters that preg requires is somewhat non-trivial. You can easily do:

```
$newcode = str_replace('eregi("', 'preg_match("/', $oldcode));
```

but then you'll still have to find where the pattern ends to add a delimiter there, as well as the `i` modifier. And you'd have to do this for every variant of ereg calls as well.